# How to simplify representing of 'include' association in use case diagram

Tags: uml, use-case

Mainly I have two questions :

- In my small project I got many use cases all of them includes another single use case ie 'Check owner status'
- Can I connect the use case to a secondary actor ie 'Cloud service'

Would you please check the following diagram, is there any better way to represent use cases?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short: `<<include>>` is not meant for functional analysis as you did it. It is meant to show individual self-standing use cases. `Check owner status` is likely some technical use case but definitely none for the `Owner`. Try concentrating on use cases that add value to their actors. Something they would spend money for.

I recommend to read Bittner/Spence.

In the past I also connected secondary actors to use cases (I further distinguished between primary and secondary be using a directed association for the primary and an undirected for the secondary). However, recently I came to the conclusion that a use case should have only one actor and the use case shall be on the boundary of the system under consideration. The need for a secondary actor simply means you have another use case (Bittner/Spence use secondary actors on UCs, though).

Comment: Since  "**check owner status**" use case is not a functional use case, should I document it in narrative use cases

Comment: Make it a constraint (pre-condition). Later in the technical design this will be converted to a technical use case (if needed). But on a business level it's not more than a constraint.

Comment: You might want to read this thread: https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/143183-6000866789691580416

Comment: Thomas makes an important point.  Use cases should focus on business, functional, or technical logic (usually business), and shouldn't mix them.  I've never used use cases in anything but a business context, as there are better diagrams to go into the detail needed in functional and technical specifications.

Comment: @BobRodes Quite some time ago when I did not have that much experience my group tried to introduce so called "technical use cases" to describe functionality on a technical/programming level. I never felt good with that and with my todays background I'd never use that construct again. UC is for business only.

Comment: Yeah, it strikes me as an enormous stretch.  Kind of like trying to explain nuclear physics with Shakespearean English.